# NET to GROSS UK Tax and NI Accurate

Tags: calculus

If I was getting NET 1500 per month or **18000** per year how would I work out my Gross salary?

I know the following:

Tax Rate = **20%** and Tax free amount = **10600**

NI Rate = **12%** and NI free amount = **8060**

Having a nightmare trying to find a formula to work this out... the answer should be:

approx 22000
Tax paid = 2280
NI Paid = 1672.80

Comment: Are the obligations computed off the Gross?  Suppose, for example, Gross was $11,000$.  Then I assume I owe tax on $400$, no?  that would be $80$.  When I then compute how much NI (whatever that is) I owe do I use the gross figure of $11,000$ or do I deduct the tax and compute NI on $10,920$?

Comment: both NI and Tax are on the gross. So 22000 would have a taxable amount of 11400 (22000 - 10600) meaning tax would be 2280. Similarly for NI 22000 - 8060, then 12% = 1672.80. trying to work the other way around given the net not the gross.

Comment: Ok...but then Net = Gross - tax - NI = Gross -.2\times (Gross-10600)-.12\times (Gross - 8060)$ where I am assuming that Gross is above  both thresholds.  Now it's just algebra.

Comment: We are trying to work out the Gross not the NET. NET is 18000 we know that, we need to add to it the Tax paid and the NI paid to give the Gross but unsure how to do this. can you show me an example using the numbers I provided? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume, for simplicity, that the Gross is above $10,600$. (obviously true in this case).

We have:  $$Net = Gross - .2\times (Gross-10600)-.12\times (Gross-8060)$$

Expanding the right hand gives us:  $$Net=.68\times Gross+3087.2\implies Gross=\frac {Net-3087.2}{.68}$$

Plugging in $Net=18000$ we get $Gross=21930.59$

Comment: Wow... been a while since I did maths but kind of get it. how did you get the value 3087.2?

Comment: $.2\times 10600 = 2120$, $.12\times 8060=967.2$, $2120+967.2=3087.2$.  That number represents the obligations you are forgiven because of the two thresholds.  That is to say, if you reset the two thresholds to $0$ then you would owe this much more.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer spent hours trying to work it out, and you make it look simple haha :D

Comment: if I do 18000 + 3087.2 / 0.68 I get 31010?

Comment: Sorry, I have a sign error.  I will edit.

Comment: Is it clear now?

Comment: awesome thanks again